# Multiple Where Condition in rawQuery Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I Have A Table as Shown Below

```
number  unit  Value     
 77      km    ss
 74      km    aa
 77      m     ww
 78      m     ee
 77      km    ii
 74      m     pp
```

I am writing a Range Query to get the nearest Values. i am using where condition to test only number. now i need to modify this query to check unit also. my Query looks like

```
  cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_DOF+" WHERE ABS("+inputNumber+" - number)=(SELECT MIN(ABS("+inputNumber+" - number)) FROM "+TABLE_DOF+") AND ABS("+inputNumber+" - number<=5", null);
```

If the input number is 77, then I am getting three rows

```
 number  unit  Value     
 77      km    ss
 77      m     ww
 77      km    ii
```

I also need to check for unit here. Any help will be Appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Seems like you've posted more or less the same question four times recently. Please don't post duplicates. Instead, you can edit your older questions on the same problem to better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you use query() instead of rawQuery() especially if you're not expert at creating valid SQL statements. That said, just add another AND to the WHERE clause.

```
String unit = "km";
cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_DOF+
" WHERE ABS("+inputNumber+" - number)=(SELECT MIN(ABS("+
inputNumber+" - number)) FROM "+TABLE_DOF+
") AND ABS("+inputNumber+" - number<=5) AND unit = " + unit, null)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Actually I am getting null pointer Exception.(no such column km)

Comment: that's odd, km is not being used as a column name. Maybe post exact new code and exception message?

Comment: Thank you :) now its working.. I Changed a bit in the Query.. new Query Looks Like     cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_DOF+
" WHERE unit = '" + unit + "' AND ABS("+inputNumber+" - number)=(SELECT MIN(ABS("+
inputNumber+" - number)) FROM "+TABLE_DOF+
") AND ABS("+inputNumber+" - number<=5) , null)

Answer (score 0):

Hi just us AND with yours WHERE clause,have try as follows

```
String unit = "km";

String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_DOF+
" WHERE ABS("+inputNumber+" - number)=(SELECT MIN(ABS("+
inputNumber+" - number)) FROM "+TABLE_DOF+
") AND ABS("+inputNumber+" - number<=5) AND unit = " + unit;

cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
```